# JSON Android login validation via mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, authentication

I am making a login screen and when testing the code,it always validates both wrong and right inputs and enters the home screen.The PHP works as it can tell which data are found in the database.Heres the code:

loginActivity.java

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class loginDosen extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txKodeDosen,txPassword;
    String KodeDosen,password;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String loginURL ="http://192.168.43.217/test/DosenPublikasi/loginDosen.php";
    StringRequest request;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_dosen);

    txKodeDosen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txKodeDosen);
    txPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txPassword);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(loginDosen.this);
}

public void Login(View view) {
    if(txKodeDosen.getText().toString().equals("") ){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Kode Dosen Field is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(txKodeDosen.getText().toString().charAt(0)!='D'){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Must have D in the start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(txKodeDosen.length() !=5 ){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Must be 5 characters long",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(txPassword.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Password Field is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        JSONObject Login = new JSONObject();
        try {
            Login.put("kodeDosen", txKodeDosen.getText().toString());
            Login.put("password", txPassword.getText().toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginURL, Login,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()

                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SharedPreferences DataDosen = getSharedPreferences("Dosen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = DataDosen.edit();
                        editor.putString("kodeDosen", txKodeDosen.getText().toString());
                        editor.putString("password", txPassword.getText().toString());
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(loginDosen.this, homepageDosen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
        requestQueue.add(jsonobjectrequest);
    }


}



public void Back(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(loginDosen.this, registrasiDosen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

heres the php

```
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
//print_r($data);

$kodeDosen =$data["kodeDosen"];
$password = $data["password"];

$message = array("message"=>"Data found");
$failure = array("mesage"=>"Data not found");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dosen WHERE kodeDosen ='$kodeDosen' and password = '$password'";

//echo $kodeDosen;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1) {
    echo json_encode($message);
}else {
    echo json_encode($failure);
}
?>
```

the json works but when the login button is used,it will always enter the next screen even if the input doesnt match any data from the database

Comment: You are never testing the contents of the returned response (you're only showing it in a Toast) before firing your Intent, so it will go to the next screen in all cases.

Comment: that is because you don't check if server responds with `Data found` or `Data not found`

Comment: reduce php code like this:- `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo json_encode($message);
}else {
    echo json_encode($failure);
}
?>`  And then check at android end that `data found` or `not found`

Comment: quentino97  check the answer below and tell us worked or not?

Comment: when i checked the android end code,i got this error message: 
 unhandled expression:org.json.JSONExeption

Comment: Both got a unhandled expression error above when i tried typing them,does this have something to do with my php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Seems like you saved the plain password.It's a big loophole to the sytem.try to use `password-hashing` to protect your password.

2.Try to use `prepared statements` to prevent from `SQL INJECTION`.The current code is wide-open for it.

3.Check ***`data is coming or not`*** at Android-end and then proceed further accordingly.

Do like below:-

***PHP end:-***

```
<?php
include 'connectdb.php';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$kodeDosen =$data["kodeDosen"];
$password = $data["password"];

$message = array("message"=>"Data found");
$failure = array("mesage"=>"Data not found");

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_dosen WHERE kodeDosen =? and password = ?")) {

   /* bind parameters for markers */
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $kodeDosen,$password);

   /* execute query */
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

   /* store result */
   mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

   if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
      echo json_encode($message);
   }else {
      echo json_encode($failure);
   }

}
?>
```

***Android end (i am not an android coder so I am giving simple logic only):-***

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
   if(check that message is "data found"){
     // if yes then proceed further
   }else if(check that message is "Data not found")){
     //if yes show some error message and do further process
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say check data is coming out ,when i test the code,it showed the response correctly(if a data is in the database it says "Data found" and if not then "Data not found")does this mean the data is accepted,if not,then how to make android accept the data?

Comment: @quentino97 I am not an android coder, I just saw the syntax to answer the android part. The main concern is to reduce the PHP code as well as make it bulletproof against `SQL INJECTION`. What my concern is that you need to check the message at the Android end what you send through PHP to proceed accordingly.like if `data not found` then stop there itself and don't proceed further.

Comment: Ok,sorry about asking you that,i thougth you have knowlege of android programming.Your php code works when i tested in the postman by the way(it correctly states which data is in the database).

Comment: @quentino97 ok, now you have to find out how you can check the message coming from PHP to your android end

Answer (score 0):

You should put in the response block the following condition

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
   if(response.getString("message").equals("Data found")){
    Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    SharedPreferences DataDosen = getSharedPreferences("Dosen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = DataDosen.edit();
    editor.putString("kodeDosen", txKodeDosen.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("password", txPassword.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(loginDosen.this, homepageDosen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }else{
    Toast.makeText(loginDosen.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```